# How to take text from a cell and input it into VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, email, text, cell

What I am trying to do is basically you click a button, it brings up the Excel MailEnvelope to send an email, and you can then send it off to the relevant button email address'.

However one of the email addresses needs to be modifiable by the end user.

So I want a drop down where you select said email, and it then inputs that into the VBA code.

I know basically nothing about VBA and I could not find a way of doing this by searching around the web.

I figured I need some way of setting a variable to read a cell (the drop down cell), and then input that into the MailEnvelope Item.CC but I was struggling.

Any help would be appreciated.

This is what I have so far;

```
Sub Send_Range_Email()

' Select the range of cells on the active worksheet.
ActiveSheet.Range("B6:D302").Select

' Show the envelope on the ActiveWorkbook.
ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = True

' Set the optional introduction field thats adds
' some header text to the email body. It also sets
' the To, CC and Subject lines.

With ActiveSheet.MailEnvelope
  .Introduction = ""
  .Item.To = "Email 0"
  .Item.Subject = "Email Tracker Results"
  .Item.CC = "Email 1" & text input here & "Email 2"
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Assuming the email address is in `A1`, you can do `.Item.CC = "email 1" & ","& Range("A1").Value &", " & "Email 2"`...is that what you're trying? (I purposefully split the commas out to their own string, just to make clear you'll likely need to separate the emails somehow.  (You can use just `"Email 1, " & Range("A1").Value & ", Email 2")

Comment: That worked perfectly thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using formulas, if you want to put a variable in there, just break it apart and add in the variable.  As commented,

```
.Item.CC = "email 1" & "," & Range("A1").Value & ", " & "Email 2"
```

So to make super clear, say we want to add `A1`'s value in this string: `str = The man lives in STATE all the time` by doing `str = "The man lives in " & Range("A1").Value & " all the time"`